# MySQL Trigger and Error Code 1362

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

So I have the following query for a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_log_update BEFORE UPDATE on user_log
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into user_log
(id, user_id, name, username, password, email, user_type_id, created)
VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.user_id, OLD.name, OLD.username, OLD.password, OLD.email, OLD.user_type_id, OLD.created);
IF (OLD.id = 1) THEN
SET OLD.id = OLD.id +1;
END IF;
SELECT * FROM user_log;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to execute this part of the script, I get `Error Code: 1362. Updating of OLD row is not allowed in trigger`

I don't know why I got this error and I don't see anything wrong in the syntax.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So, increment `new` instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_log_update BEFORE UPDATE on user_log
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into user_log(id, user_id, name, username, password, email, user_type_id, created)
        VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.user_id, OLD.name, OLD.username, OLD.password, OLD.email, OLD.user_type_id, OLD.created);
    IF (OLD.id = 1) THEN
        SET NEW.id = OLD.id +1;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How do I deal with "Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger"?

Comment: Remove the final `select`, as I just did.

Answer (score 0):

```
 delimiter |
create trigger display_student_table 
        before insert on student_table
        for each row

Begin
    set new.student_name=trim(new.student_name);
    set new.branch=trim(new.branch);
    set new.address=trim(address);
End ;

|
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Please add some explanation, what this code does and why it is the solution to the problem